Issues with Executing Raw SQL Query Using Pony ORM in Flask Application
I'm currently working on a Flask application using Pony ORM for database management. My goal is to fetch all products along with their associated category and unit names from a MySQL database. While I can perform basic CRUD operations without issues, I'm facing difficulties executing a JOIN query to join multiple tables using Pony ORM
    def list_products(self):
        try:
            query = Product.select().join(Category).join(Unit).order_by(Product.id)
            product_dicts = [p.to_dict(with_collections=True) for p in query]
            return jsonify({'list': product_dicts}), 200

        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

The Problem:
I am trying to write a function that retrieves all products along with their category and unit names. However, my current implementation is causing a 500 Internal Server Error, and I suspect it’s due to the way I'm handling the results or how am i handling the query itself.
My Function:
Here's the code for the function that attempts to execute the raw SQL query
def list_products(self):
    try:
        with db_session:
            query_result = select("""SELECT 
                                       p.id AS product_id,
                                       p.name AS product_name,
                                       c.name AS category_name,
                                       u.name AS unit_name
                                   FROM 
                                       Product p
                                   JOIN 
                                       Category c ON p.category = c.id
                                   JOIN 
                                       Unit u ON p.unit = u.id""")
        
        
        product_dicts = []
        for row in query_result:
            product_dict = {
                'product_id': row.product_id,
                'product_name': row.product_name,
                'category_name': row.category_name,
                'unit_name': row.unit_name
            }
            product_dicts.append(product_dict)

        return jsonify({'list': product_dicts}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

These are the modals
from pony.orm import Database, Required, Optional, PrimaryKey, Set
from datetime import datetime

db = Database()

class Unit(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    products = Set('Product')
    created_date = Optional(datetime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())
    updated_date = Optional(datetime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())

class Category(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    products = Set('Product')
    suppliers = Set('CategorySupplier')
    created_date = Optional(datetime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())
    updated_date = Optional(datetime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())

class Product(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    image_name = Optional(str)
    category = Required(Category)
    unit = Required(Unit)
    expiration_date = Optional(str)
    unit_price = Optional(float)
    stock = Set('Stock')
    inbound_stocks = Set('InboundStock')
    outbound_stocks = Set('OutboundStock')
    clients = Set('ProductClient')
    suppliers = Set('ProductSupplier')
    inventory_audits = Set('InventoryAudit')
    order_items = Set('OrderItem')
    returns = Set('Return')
    created_date = Optional(datetime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())
    updated_date = Optional(datetime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())


Error:
The function consistently returns a 500 Internal Server Error. When I inspect the logs, the error message is not very informative, and I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm handling the raw SQL query and results.
Additional Information:
Database: MySQL
ORM: Pony ORM
Framework: Flask
i was able to solve the problem, the issue mainly was in the query syntax since pony.orm uses python for runing sql queries, there was a lack of info regarding join in the doc which got me confused so i've been trying some dumb stuff in order to solve it
Here is the solution i found
    def list_products(self):
    with db_session:
        query = select(
            (p, c, u)
            for p in Product
            for c in JOIN(p.category)
            for u in JOIN(p.unit)
        )
        product_dicts = [
            {
                'id': p.id,
                'name': p.name,
                'unit_price': p.unit_price,
                'expiration_date': p.expiration_date,
                'category': c.name,
                'unit': u.name
            }
            for p, c, u in query
        ]
        return jsonify({'list': product_dicts}), 200


@snakecharmerb thank you i removed the try except ad i was able to trace the issue,  the issue was in the querry syntax since pony.orm uses python syntax and there was a lack of info provided in the join section in their doc which got me confused
i'll post the solution  found if anyone had that kind of issue in the future
